# Consider defining a bean of type 'com.security.learnspringsecurity.Repositories.UserRepo' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-bean

please refer the hierarchy

```
package com.security.learnspringsecurity.Repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.security.learnspringsecurity.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

I'm trying to access the repo interface in service class, but it's throwing error as mentioned 'Consider defining a bean of type 'com.security.learnspringsecurity.Repositories.UserRepo' in your configuration.'

please help me to solve this

Comment: How are you configuring this?

Comment: one quick question `component scan will scan for beans to children package also right?` because in root spring boot class I mentioned @component scan for that repo package, it's working now. But not satisfied. pls answer this.

Comment: solved this issue by having `spring.data.jpa.repository.enable=true` property.